# How to Link objecst with each other using java

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I have the below classes and it has multiple objects. I need to link these objects with each other using java.

```
class Test{
    int value = 0;

    public Test(int value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg){
        //creating three objects
        Test test1 = new Test(10);
        Test test2 = new Test(60);
        Test test3 = new Test(80);
    }
}
```

How can I link test1, test2,test3 objects each other?.

Comment: how do you mean: link?

Comment: link means  to point objects each other

Comment: You definately need to explain your goal in more details. What do you want to acheive *in the end* ?

Comment: if they have unique id's, you can link to those in your objects themselves. It depends on your requirements

Comment: You don't "point" the same object types to each other, you store them in a list or map.

Comment: I need to create a structure as a linked list and these objects should be represented as link nodes.

Comment: @Guy that doesn't really link the objects to each other

Comment: @Stultuske My point exactly.

Comment: Keep those objects into linked list.

Comment: @Guy if the requirement is to have them point to each other, your point is a bit pointless

Answer (score 1):

If you want single linked list:

```
public class Test {

    private int value = 0;

    private Test next;

    public Test(int value){
        this(value, null);
    }

    public Test(int value, Test next){
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Test getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Test next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg){
        Test test1 = new Test(10);

        // via constructor
        Test test2 = new Test(60, test1);

        // via setter
        Test test3 = new Test(80);
        test3.setNext(test2);

        System.out.println(test3.getNext().getNext().getValue());
    }
}
```

In this example 'next' is [reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3) to Test object. You can assign value to reference via constructor or setter method.

> An object is a class instance or an array.
>
> The reference values (often just references) are pointers to these
>   objects, and a special null reference, which refers to no object.

Note, that test1, test2, test3 are references too. The 'new' operator creates new instance of class Test and returns reference to created object.

If your goal is not to create the linked list structure itself, just use [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) or any other collection from JDK.

Comment: dangerous way of working. you're just a few changes away from a StackOverflowError

Comment: @Stultuske You're *always* just a few changes away from a StackOverflowError.

Comment: @Michael reason to more not to get closer to the issue on purpose :). Though your solution is a bit safer, personally I would only store the id of the previous/next element, provided it's a unique one

Comment: @Stultuske Storing an ID does not prevent an infinite loop. What if I accidentally assign something its own ID? It's the same problem as assigning something a reference to itself, just with an extra layer of indirection. Of course you have to be careful in situations like this, but there are definitely valid use-cases. `LinkedList.Node`, for example.

Comment: I never mentioned assigning a reference to itself.

Answer (score 1):

"Links" are called references in Java. If an object needs to point to another object, it needs a field to hold that reference as part of its internal state.

The field should be of the same type as the class. You can populate that field via a setter, via the constructor, etc.

```
class Test{
    int value = 0;
    Test neighbour;

    public Test(int value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setNeighbour(Test neighbour) {
        this.neighbour = neighbour;
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg){
        //creating three objects
        Test test1 = new Test(10);
        Test test2 = new Test(60);
        Test test3 = new Test(80);

        test3.setNeighbour(test2);
    }
}
```

`test3` now has a "link" to test2 and can call its methods.